# I get the following warnings 'architecture i386'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fmdb, mbprogresshud

I get the following warnings from my xCode project. How do i get rid of them?

note: I ma using `MBProgessHud` and `FMDB`

```
   Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/MBProgressHUD.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386

    Warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/SampleProj/../FMDatabase.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check the "Build Phases" tab, in compile sources section, *.h files shouldn't be there.